# NDSolve giving the wrong solution?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm considering the non-linear second order ODE DE $=0$, with DE given by

```
DE = y[x] (2 + y[x]) y''[x] + 2 x y[x] (2 + y[x]) y'[x]/(-1 + x^2) - (1 + 2 y[x]) y'[x]^2  
+ 4 (1 + y[x]) (2 + y[x])^2/(-1 + x^2)^2.
```

on the domain $x\geq 0$. The initial conditions are $y[0]=0,$ $y'[0]=-4$. Now I know that a solution is given by $ysol=\frac{-4x}{1+3x}$, which Mathematica can indeed verify. Now I'm trying to acquire this solution with NDSolve. When I use the following input

```
NDSolve[{DE == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == -4}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Mathematica gives the error

```
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
```

Now I am assuming out that the problem is the fact that the coefficient in the ODE in front of the second derivative vanishes at $x=0$. Therefore I tried using a slightly different initial condition. The input I used is:

```
eps =10^-10
Sol = NDSolve[{DE == 0, y[0] == -eps, y'[0] == -4}, y, {x, 0, 10}];
Plot[{y[x] /. Sol, ysol[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Here $ysol$ is the known solution I gave above. The output is

[image: Output]

hence Mathematica does not give the solution I already know.

Questions:

- Is the solution Mathematica is giving me correct because of the slightly different initial conditions?
- How can I make Mathematica give the solution I already know? I.e. what should I change in my input?
- It seems Mathematica cannot solve the ODE with the initial conditions that I know. Is this an error caused by the numerical solution method, or does this mean that the ODE actually does not have a unique solution?

Comment: do not have time now, but quick comment: you have non-linear ode. A non-linear ode can admit a singular solution (which can't be obtained from the general solution by giving the constants of integration specific values). Another solution is `y=-2`. Another is `y=(-4*((x^4-2*x^2+1)/(x^4+8*x^3+18*x^2+8*x+1))^(1/2)*x^4-20*((x^4-2*x^2+1)/(x^4+8*x^3+18*x^2+8*x+1))^(1/2)*x^3-4*x^4-24*((x^4-2*x^2+1)/(x^4+8*x^3+18*x^2+8*x+1))^(1/2)*x^2-16*x^3-20*((x^4-2*x^2+1)/(x^4+8*x^3+18*x^2+8*x+1))^(1/2)*x-32*x^2-4*((x^4-2*x^2+1)/(x^4+8*x^3+18*x^2+8*x+1))^(1/2)-16*x-4)/(3*x^4+8*x^3+14*x^2+8*x+3)` as well as the..

Comment: ... the one you showed `y=-4*x/(1+3*x)`. The point is, these are singular solutions. There is a singularity in your ode, which is why NDSolve gives a 1/0 error. So, there is nothing wrong with `NDSolve`. Notice that `DSolve` did not solve this.

Comment: Thanks, that does clear things up a bit. With the singularity in the ODE, do you mean the fact that at $0$ we have that the ODE becomes $0*y''=0$? Can I conclude that for every value $y''(0)$ there is a different solution? If so, can Mathematica find these?

Comment: @Nasser I'm also curious how you found your second solution

Answer (score 3):

The DE has problems at `y[x] == 0` as noted, but also at `x == 1`, where there is a pole of order 2.  This suggests that numerical issues near the singularities could cause substantial error to accumulate.  One can use `Piecewise` to substitute the limiting value at a discontinuity, but this won't cure any numerical instability in the neighborhood of the discontinuity.

One can remove the `1/0` errors with `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"`, but the numerical trouble persists.  The code below results in a plot similar to, if not worse than, the OP's workaround.

```
sol = NDSolve[{DE == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == -4, y''[0] == 24}, 
  y, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]

Plot[{(-4 x)/(1 + 3 x), y[x] /. First[sol]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see that the second derivative is not calculated very well near `x == 0` by this method:

```
foo = D[(-4 x)/(1 + 3 x), x, x];
Plot[{y''[x] /. First[sol], foo}, {x, 0, 0.001}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Piecewise` helps near `x == 0`, but it fails at `x == 1`:

```
sys = {y''[x] == 
   Piecewise[{{y''[x] /. First@Solve[DE == 0, y''[x]] // Expand // 
       Simplify, y[x] != 0}}, 24], y[0] == 0, y'[0] == -4};
sol = NDSolve[sys, y, {x, 0, 10}];
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 1.00008646582443`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
Plot[{(-4 x)/(1 + 3 x), y[x] /. First[sol]}, {x, 0, 1.}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get a solution that crosses the discontinuity is difficult.  The numerical evidence* suggests the discontinuity is unstable and virtually impossible without some preconditioning.  The best thing I have to offer is to start the integration at `x == 1`.  While there are some numerical issues near `x == 0`, integrating toward it seems stable.
(*I tried `WhenEvent[x == 1, "CrossDiscontinuity"]`, increasing `WorkingPrecision`, and such stuff.  Whenever it integrated past `x == 1`, there was a large error.)

To start the integration at `x == 1`, I tried to analyze the DE and come up with a solution (pretending not to know the OP's desired outcome).  It turns out there are two choices for `y[1]`, so that didn't work.  And for the desired `y[1] == -1`, the choice for `y'[1]` appears to be free, so again I had to use the OP's formula to determine the initial value.  I determined these constraints by examining the series expansion of the DE.  The default value for `y''[1]` is also determined this way.

```
SeriesCoefficient[DE, {x, 1, -2}] == 0 // Solve
SeriesCoefficient[DE, {x, 1, -1}] == 0 /. y[1] -> -1 // Solve
SeriesCoefficient[DE, {x, 1, 0}] == 0 /. y[1] -> -1 // Solve
(*
  {{y[1] -> -2}, {y[1] -> -2}, {y[1] -> -1}}
  {{}}
  {{y''[1] -> y'[1] (-1 + 2 y'[1])}}
*)
```

Note that `"StiffnessSwitching"` is needed to step through the muck around `x == 1`:

```
ypp[x0_?NumericQ, y0_?NumericQ, yp0_?NumericQ] = Piecewise[
   {{y''[x] /. First@Solve[DE == 0, y''[x]] /. {x -> x0, y[x] -> y0, 
       y'[x] -> yp0}, x0 != 1}},
   yp0 (-1 + 2 yp0)];
sol = NDSolve[{y''[x] == ypp[x, y[x], y'[x]], y[1] == -1, 
   y'[1] == -1/4}, y, {x, 0, 10}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]

Plot[{(-4 x)/(1 + 3 x), y[x] /. First[sol]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[5], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's been so long since I'd have to look up again what this was all about, but I promise to do so in a while and check your answer.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck No problem. I was working on something else, searching the site, when I got some help that solved my problem (the `"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"` trick). I thought I'd try it out on some the related questions I had found to see how robust it was. Of course, the trick failed here, but in an interesting way. I'm still not fully sure why it failed. You can't increase `WorkingPrecision` with this trick, and you can't analyze the numerics of internal code you don't have access to.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on this (solving non-linear odes'). But to put all what I saw here in stead of in comment is easier. Basically, you have a non-linear ode with singularity when `y(0)=0` as well due to the initial conditions. You can see this part like this:

```
de = y[x] (2 + y[x]) y''[x] + 2 x y[x] (2 + y[x]) y'[x]/(-1 + x^2) - 
  (1 + 2 y[x]) y'[x]^2 + 4 (1 + y[x]) (2 + y[x])^2/(-1 + x^2)^2;
sol=Solve[de == 0, y''[x]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What happens in the above when `y(0)=0`?

```
rhs = y''[x] /. sol
rhs /. {x -> 0, y[x] -> 0, y'[0] -> -4}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So, your initial conditions leads to singularity, without even solving the ode. i.e. the above is saying `y''(0)` is infinity. But if `y'(0)=-4`, then it `y''(0)` should be zero. right? So, your initial conditions and the ode do not agree, at least from initial look as in the above.

But since this is a non-linear ode, they have what is called a singular solutions, if you google `singular solution of nonlinear ode` you see articles on this. These do not come from setting initial conditions to the general solution.  Mathematica `DSolve` can't solve this in closed form, and `NDsolve` can't due to the above problem with initial conditions (after all, it is a numerical solver).

Maple can give a singular solution but parametrized. By changing the parameters, it gave me back the solutions I gave.  Here is the code if you are interested:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Taking this solution to Mathematica and looking at it:

```
sol = -ArcTanh[x] + (1/2)*ArcTanh[(1/4)*(4*C1*(2 + y[x]) + 8)/(4 - 2*C1*y[x]^2 -
  4*C1*y[x])^(1/2)] - (1/2)*ArcTanh[C1 + 1] == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now solving for `y[x]` and changing `C1` gives the different solutions I showed

```
sol2 = y[x] /. Solve[sol, y[x]];  (*2 solutions*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For example, looking at the first one, change C1

```
Limit[First@sol2, C1 -> Infinity]
(*  -2  *)

Limit[First@sol2, C1 -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that at `C1=0` the solution is not defined.

Used Maple 18.01 and Mathematica 10.01 both on windows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helps. I'm a bit confused about the following comment: "But if `y'(0)=-4`, then it `y''(0)` should be zero. right?" Why is that? E.g. in the solution $y=-4x/(1+3x)$ we have `y'(0)=-4` and `y''(0)=24`.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's 24 or 0 or anything, I don't think my ODE contradicts this. I.e. I don't think it shows that $y''$ should be diverging. Rather, it's indeterminate because with $y'(0)=-4$ one gets $\infty-\infty$. If you replace `rhs /. {x -> 0, y[x] -> 0, y'[0] -> -4}` in your answer by `rhs /. {x -> 0, y[x] -> 0, y'[x] -> -4}`, Mathematica also returns Indeterminate, and imposing $y=-4x+ C x^2$ and Tayloring yields $y''(0)=2C$ as it should. Hence I don't think it's true that the initial conditions don't agree with the ODE, correct?